Streaming in .NET 6 Blazor WASM Core hosted
I have this method in my controller that sends out messages but in chunks:
[HttpPost]
public async Task Chat([FromBody] ChatRequest request)
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
    Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "0");

    try
    {
        var responseStream = _chatService.ChatAsync(request.UserInput!, request.History!);
        
        await foreach (var chunk in responseStream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(chunk);
            await Response.WriteAsync($"data: {chunk}\n\n");
            await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Response.WriteAsync($"data: Error: {ex.Message}\n\n");
        await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("END");
        await Response.WriteAsync($" --{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")} \n\n");
        await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
    }
}

Using Postman, I can get each word of a message one by one.
In my client side, I created a page and a service that calls this API endpoint
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ChatAsync(
    string userInput,
    string history,
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var request = new ChatRequest
    {
        UserInput = userInput,
        History = history
    };

    var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/Chats")
    {
        Content = JsonContent.Create(request)
    };

    httpRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/event-stream"));

    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken);
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"Read line: {line}");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;

        string chunk;

        if (line.StartsWith("data: ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            chunk = line.Substring(6);
        }
        else
        {
            chunk = line;
        }

        yield return chunk;
    }
}

Code-behind for my HTML:
private async Task SendMessage()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput) || isSending)
        return;

    isSending = true;

    messages.Add(new ChatMessage { Content = userInput, IsUser = true });
    var currentUserInput = userInput;
    userInput = "";

    var botMessage = new ChatMessage { Content = "", IsUser = false };
    messages.Add(botMessage);
    StateHasChanged();

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting to receive chunks...");

        await foreach (var chunk in ChatService.ChatAsync(currentUserInput, history, cts.Token))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received chunk: {chunk}");
            botMessage.Content += chunk;
            StateHasChanged();
            await InvokeAsync(() => JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollToBottom", "chatMessages"));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished receiving chunks.");
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        botMessage.Content += " [Message was interrupted]";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        botMessage.Content = $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}";
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception occurred: {ex}");
    }

    history += $"User: {currentUserInput}\nBot: {botMessage.Content}\n";
    isSending = false;

    StateHasChanged();
}

Why is it that I cannot get the message chunk by chunk or word by word? What happens is it waits for the whole reply then renders it. I can get the whole reply. The only problem is, I need it to be able to render it to the UI each time it receives a word from the API and render it. Just like an ordinary Generative AI. If I leave it as it is (wait for the whole reply and then render it) if the reply is lengthy, then it would take time before i can actually render it in the UI. It would cause a bad user experience.
I am using Blazor WASM core hosted in .NET 6.

The delay you are facing it might be because server is buffering the response before sending it all at once, which would explain the long wait for longer messages. Make sure that after each chunk of data is sent to the client, you are flushing the response. If the FlushAsync method is not called, the server may buffer the data and send it all at once at the end, causing delays in the client-side experience. and to send response like AI word by word you could try calling StateHasChanged() right after each chunk is appended to the bot's message so that Blazor knows to re-render the component.
and add the await Task.Delay(65);  which can give you the typing effect. here you can see the result without using delay:


Here is my sample which shows the similar response as you mentioned:
Client:
Chat.razor:
@page "/chat"
@using ChatApp.Client.Services
@inject ChatService ChatService
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h3>Chat</h3>

<div id="chatMessages" class="chat-container">
    @foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        <div>@message.Content</div>
    }
    
    @* @if (isBotTyping) 
    {
        <div><em>Bot is typing...</em></div>
    } *@
</div>

<input @bind="userInput" @bind:event="oninput" placeholder="Enter your message..." />
<button @onclick="SendMessage" disabled="@(isSending)">Send</button>

@code {
    private List<ChatMessage> messages = new();
    private string userInput;
    private bool isSending;
    private bool isBotTyping; // Flag to indicate whether the bot is typing
    private CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

    private async Task SendMessage()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput) || isSending)
            return;

        isSending = true;
        var currentUserInput = userInput;
        userInput = "";

        var userMessage = new ChatMessage { Content = currentUserInput, IsUser = true };
        messages.Add(userMessage);

        var botMessage = new ChatMessage { Content = "", IsUser = false };
        messages.Add(botMessage);

        isBotTyping = true; // Start typing indicator
        StateHasChanged(); // Update the UI to display user's message and typing indicator immediately

        try
        {
            // Read and display each chunk word-by-word
            await foreach (var chunk in ChatService.ChatAsync(currentUserInput, "", cts.Token))
            {
                botMessage.Content += chunk + " ";  // Append word
                StateHasChanged();  // Render immediately after receiving each word
                await Task.Delay(30);  // Small delay to simulate typing effect
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            botMessage.Content = $"Error: {ex.Message}";
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        finally
        {
            isBotTyping = false; // Stop typing indicator
            isSending = false;   // Allow user to send a new message
            StateHasChanged();   // Final update to show full bot message and remove typing indicator
        }
    }

    private class ChatMessage
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public bool IsUser { get; set; }
    }
}

ChatService.cs:
using ChatApp.Shared;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ChatApp.Client.Services
{
    public class ChatService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public ChatService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ChatAsync(string userInput, string history, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var request = new ChatRequest
            {
                UserInput = userInput,
                History = history
            };

            var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/Chat")
            {
                Content = JsonContent.Create(request)
            };

            httpRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/event-stream"));

            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken);
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;

                if (line.StartsWith("data: ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    yield return line.Substring(6); // Yield each word to the UI
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

Server:
ChatService.cs:
namespace ChatApp.Server.Services
{
    public interface IChatService
    {
        IAsyncEnumerable<string> ChatAsync(string userInput, string history);
    }

    public class ChatService : IChatService
    {
        public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ChatAsync(string userInput, string history)
        {
            var botResponse = $"Bot: Here is a simulated response to your input: {userInput}.";
            var words = botResponse.Split(' ');

            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                // Optionally adjust delay based on the size of the response
                await Task.Delay(30);  // Reduce delay to speed up response
                yield return word;
            }
        }
    }


}

ChatController.cs:
using ChatApp.Server.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ChatApp.Shared;

namespace ChatApp.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ChatController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IChatService _chatService;

        public ChatController(IChatService chatService)
        {
            _chatService = chatService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task Chat([FromBody] ChatRequest request)
        {
            // Headers for Server-Sent Events (SSE)
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
            Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
            Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "0");

            try
            {
                var responseStream = _chatService.ChatAsync(request.UserInput!, request.History!);

                await foreach (var chunk in responseStream)
                {
                    // Send chunk as soon as it's available
                    await Response.WriteAsync($"data: {chunk}\n\n");

                    // Flush the response immediately to prevent buffering
                    await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Response.WriteAsync($"data: Error: {ex.Message}\n\n");
                await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                await Response.WriteAsync($"-- {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")}\n\n");
                await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }


}


